# Bring all fields in a table using NHibernate QueryOver<>

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, queryover

I am using Nhibernate's `QueryOver<>` to read from an existing database.  I know there are records in the table, but it is only displaying the field names when it generates the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        myConfiguration = new Configuration();
        myConfiguration.Configure();
        mySessionFactory = myConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();

        IList<DriverHeader> drivers;
        using (ISession session = mySessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            drivers = session.QueryOver<DriverHeader>().List();
        }

        return View(drivers);
    }
```

Comment: *Would like to assist if possible, but really not sure what is the issue. Code seems to be reasonable...*

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Select (for the projection), one for each field that you want:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
    myConfiguration = new Configuration();
    myConfiguration.Configure();
    mySessionFactory = myConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();

    IList<DriverHeader> drivers;
    using (ISession session = mySessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        drivers = session.QueryOver<DriverHeader>()      
                         .SelectList(list => list
                         .Select(x => x.field).WithAlias(() => dtoDriverHeader.field)
                  .List();
    }

    return View(drivers);
}
```